# Highcharts legend do not refresh when updating data

Tags: highcharts

In my HighCharts implementation I'm dynamically changing the data of all series of the chart. This all works as expected, but the legend gets refreshed each time aswell causing the filtered legend to become unfiltered.

Let me explain with the following example.
If you look at this sample by HighCharts themselves you will see the legend showing 'John', 'Jane' and 'Joe' : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

If you click on John you'll only see the series of Jane and Joe. If you'd now refresh the underlieing series the legend will refresh and John his data will be visible again.

I need to prevent this from happening. Anybody got an idea on how I could do this?

FYI; I'm updating the data like this:

```
function updateSeries(data, chart, vm) {
            for (var i = 0, len = chart.series.length; i < len; i++) {
                chart.series[0].remove();
            }

            var series = calculateSeries(data, vm);

            _.each(series, function (serie) {
                chart.addSeries(serie, false);
            });

            chart.redraw();
        }
```

I'm aware that I'm actually removing and re-adding the series, but that's because I'm unsure of how to do this otherwise.

Comment: But the series are all still the same series each time? You're just updating?  Look at the series.setData() function: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData.

Comment: Changing the data instead of the entire serie does not refresh the legend. The series.setData method does the trick. Thanks!